# Overlapping areas in same range, duplicate cells

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

Consider the following code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Resize(3, 3)
Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Resize(3, 3))
Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4).Resize(3, 3))

'Shows 27, should be 19
MsgBox rng.Cells.Count

rng.ClearContents
For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
    rngCell = rngCell + 1
Next rngCell
```

The result is:

[image]

Basically the code produces one range variable which holds 3 overlapping areas. When iterating over the cells with For Each, some cells are visited more than once. Also, Cells.Count shows a higher number than the actual number of (unique) cells in the range.

How do I flatten/collapse these 3 areas so that there is no overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `rng.Address` is `$B$2:$D$4,$C$3:$E$5,$D$4:$F$6`. `Union` creates a range cover two ranges, but it doesn't remove duplicated cells.
- `mergeRng.Address` is `$B$2:$D$4,$E$3:$E$4,$F$4,$C$5:$F$5,$D$6:$F$6`.  The `mergeRng` is formed by repeatedly adding individual cells through the `Union` operation.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim mergeRng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Resize(3, 3)
    Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Resize(3, 3))
    Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4).Resize(3, 3))
    
    'Shows 27, should be 19
    Debug.Print rng.Cells.Count
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    
    For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
        If mergeRng Is Nothing Then
            Set mergeRng = rngCell
        Else
            Set mergeRng = Union(mergeRng, rngCell)
        End If
    Next rngCell
    Debug.Print mergeRng.Cells.Count
    Debug.Print mergeRng.Address
    mergeRng.ClearContents
    For Each rngCell In mergeRng.Cells
        rngCell = rngCell + 1
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object

```
Sub NoOverlap()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Cells(2, 2).Resize(3, 3)
        Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(3, 3).Resize(3, 3))
        Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(4, 4).Resize(3, 3))
    End With
    
    With rng
        .ClearContents
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    End With
    MsgBox rng.Cells.Count ' it shows 19
    
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
        rngCell = rngCell + 1
    Next
End Sub
```